# App space built using Flutter/Dart

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have created an android app using flutter/dart which has an app bar and a "Hellow world" string at the centre of the activity.
When I checked the settings of the app, it shows that this app occupies some 44Mb of the phone space.

The same app built using XML/Java occupies mere 2-3 Mb.
Why is there such a significant increase in space occupied by flutter/dart?
Can I reduce it anyhow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, Flutter apps ship with the whole runtime. There is no dependency to a specific Android SDK (if you don't use plugins) which amounts to about 7MB for simple applications.

The main issue here is that you are using a debug build, which ships the Dart VM and debug information and whatnot.

Create a release build and the size will go down to about 7MB

```
flutter build apk --release
```